# Python CMD Syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

While coding in Python I ran into this error in CMD

```
Project11.py", line 5
    if Select == 1
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my full program

```
print("Canadian to USD")

Select = input("Press 1 for Canadian to USD or 2 for USD to Canadian ")

if Select == 1
    Canadian1 = input("Canadian ")

    USD1 = int(Canadian1) * 0.63674
    print("{0}$ = ${1}".format(Canadian1, USD1))

if Select == 2
    USD2 = input("USD ")

    Canadian2 = int(USD2) * 1.5704
    print("${0}={1}$".format(USD2, Canadian2))
```

Can someone please correct the error or help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: You are missing a colon (`:`) at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: To expand upon @zvone's comment, you are missing a colon (`:`) at the end of **both** `if` statement lines

Comment: Either use `if Select == '1':` or use `Select =int(input("Press 1 for Canadian to USD or 2 for USD to Canadian "))`. Just putting `:` isn't sufficient

Comment: Sorry for not responding I was on vacation when I posted this (evidently Canada lol) and I got so caught up in things that I forgot to check and totally forgot. But I went back to look at this because I had another question on a project and I saw the notification for this and I fixed it and tested it but my results were different from what the internet said so it took me a moment but pretty quickly figured out that it was because of inflation of currencies and whatnot so I fixed it obviously and I was thinking of how it would be pretty neat (continued on next comment)

Comment: if I also added something so that it would check the internet to make sure it was accurate. I don't know if I'm that invested in this to do that but if someone else wanted to I'd love to see it and again thanks to everyone for the help. ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes and colons after `if Select == "1"` and `if Select == "2"`.

So your code would look like:

```
print("Canadian to USD")

Select = input("Press 1 for Canadian to USD or 2 for USD to Canadian ")

if Select == "1":
    Canadian1 = input("Canadian ")

    USD1 = int(Canadian1) * 0.63674
    print("{0}$ = ${1}".format(Canadian1, USD1))

if Select == "2":
    USD2 = input("USD ")

    Canadian2 = int(USD2) * 1.5704
    print("${0}={1}$".format(USD2, Canadian2))
```

Comment: Check my comment to the question. You need additional `" "` around `1` and `2` or you use `int(input....)`

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing colons after your `if statements`.

```
if int(Select) == 1:
```

and

```
if int(Select) == 2:
```

Comment: It won't enter the `if` statement even if user enters `1` as input because `type(Select)` will be `str`

Comment: I would delete the first two statements of your answer... The last two are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `if Select == '1':` and `if Select == '2':` because the input from the keyboard will be a string. You need to either convert it into `int` or just put `' '` around the string.

Alternatively you can do (also put `:` after `if` statement)

```
Select =int(input("Press 1 for Canadian to USD or 2 for USD to Canadian "))
```

Answer (score 1):

after that see that input give you a string so you should write:

```
if Select == "1":
```

In order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The "input method takes a string, so you should set the response to string or transform the input to numbers or boolean.
also make sure to add " : " after the if statement